# How to use a function with select to batch select columns

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, pyspark

I want to select columns from a dataframe,

however, I want to get the names and aliases from a config file and keep it variable.
The config.json file give me a dict like

```
conf

"data":
{
    "a":"a",
    "b":"great",
    "c":"example"
}
```

Now, I can select my columns like this:

```
from pyspark import functions as F
df= df.select
(
F.col("a").alias("a"),
F.col("b").alias("great"),
F.col("c").alias("example)
)
```

But I would rather do it in a loop.
like

```
 For all data.items(), do df=df.select(F.col(item[0]).alias(item[1]))
```

But I cannot wrap my head around it(maybe I should go to bed earlier)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.select([F.col(k).alias(v) for k, v in data.items()])`.

Full example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[ ["s1", 10, True], ["s2", 20, False] ], schema=["a", "b", "c"])

[Out]:
+---+---+-----+
|  a|  b|    c|
+---+---+-----+
| s1| 10| true|
| s2| 20|false|
+---+---+-----+

data = {
    "a":"a",
    "b":"great",
    "c":"example"
}

df = df.select([F.col(k).alias(v) for k, v in data.items()])

[Out]:
+---+-----+-------+
|  a|great|example|
+---+-----+-------+
| s1|   10|   true|
| s2|   20|  false|
+---+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do a list comprehension with the dict items.

here's an example

```py
cols = {
    "a":"a",
    "b":"great",
    "c":"example"
}

spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, 2, 3)]).toDF(['a', 'b', 'c']). \
    selectExpr(*['{0} as {1}'.format(item[0], item[1]) for item in cols.items()]). \
    show()

# +---+-----+-------+
# |  a|great|example|
# +---+-----+-------+
# |  1|    2|      3|
# +---+-----+-------+
```

Comment: would : spark.sparkContext.parallelize(mydataframe. \
    selectExpr(*['{0} as {1}'.format(item[0], item[1]) for item in cols.items()]). \
    show()
work?

Comment: @FloridaMan - simply use the dataframe before the select